# Can the tension on a rope for example diminish due to centrifugal force and if so why do we stay in orbit; what would happen if centrifugal force won?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

the rope is made of string and the centrifugal force is only slightly stronger than the centripetal force will the rope tension be enough to keep the object there the centripetal force s 3 and the centrifugal force is 2.9.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about reaction forces exerted by things like string and walls is that they adjust themselves to be just strong enough.

A string cannot be stretched. (At least the ideal strings used in physics problems can't.) If you tie one end to the ceiling and hang a weight on it, the force on the weight is $mg$. The weight pulls that hard on the string, and the string pulls back exactly that hard. This is exactly hard enough to keep the weight from stretching the string. The string doesn't pull harder than necessary. That would lift the weight.

That isn't the biggest force the string can exert. If you hang a bigger weight, the string will pull harder.

Rigid objects like walls, floors, tables, blocks, and so on are the same. If you push on a wall, the wall pushes back just hard enough to stop you from penetrating the wall. If you push harder so does the wall. If you are pulled away from the wall, the wall does not pull back. (It would if you were glued to the wall.)

In a static problem like hanging a weight, you know the weight does not accelerate. So the total force is $0$. So the tension in the string exactly matches $mg$.

Circular motion problems are similar. If an object moves in a circle, the acceleration is $v^2/r$. That comes from the acceleration needed to be deflected from a straight line into a circular path.

If a string is holding the object in a circular path and tension is the only force on the string, you know the tension in the string.

If you have a pendulum, where gravity pulls the object down and a string pulls it up, you know the total acceleration and total force because the trajectory is a circle. You can calculate the tension in the string.

If the tension was stronger than you calculate, the path would not be the circle that leaves the string straight. Strings don't pull hard enough to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it's very common mistake which beginners commit while learning about centripetal and centrifugal force.

Centrifugal force doesn't really exist !

Centrifugal force is often described as the apparent outward force experienced by an object in a rotating frame of reference. It is not a true force like gravity or electromagnetism but rather a perceived effect that arises due to the inertia of the object.

When an object is in circular motion, it tends to move in a straight line due to its inertia. However, because it is constrained to move in a circle, there is a tendency for it to "fly out" from the center of rotation. In a rotating frame of reference, observers may attribute this outward movement to a force, which is called centrifugal force.

In reality, there is no physical force pushing objects outward; it's a result of the inertia of the objects wanting to move in straight lines. Centrifugal force is considered a fictitious or pseudo-force because it only appears when viewing the motion from a rotating perspective and does not originate from any actual physical interaction.

Centripetal force is responsible for keeping an object in circular motion by constantly changing the direction of its velocity. In the absence of a centripetal force, an object would move in a straight line due to its inertia.

When an object moves in a circle, it constantly changes its direction, and this change in direction implies acceleration. According to Newton's second law, there must be a force acting on the object to cause this acceleration. The centripetal force provides this necessary inward force, preventing the object from moving in a straight line and keeping it in a circular path.

So, in essence, the centripetal force acts as a "center-seeking" force, continually adjusting the object's direction to maintain circular motion. It doesn't pull the object towards the center but ensures the necessary acceleration to keep it in a circular path.

The question *the rope is made of string and the centrifugal force is only slightly stronger than the centripetal force will the rope tension be enough to keep the object there the centripetal force s 3 and the centrifugal force is 2.9* is flawed in reality, perhaps it raised in your mind due to corrupt understanding of those phenomenon. Centrifugal and centripetal are always equal and opposite to each other, because centrifugal is nothing but kind of *adjustment* which we have done, centrifugal force is infact calculated on basis of centripetal force taking it's magnitude and reversing the direction.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, if you find yourself trying to balance centrifugal force and centripetal force then you have made a mistake, since these two forces apply in different reference frames.

In a stationary reference frame the tension in the rope provides the centripetal force that keeps the object on the end of the rope moving in a circle. There is no need to balance the tension in the string with an equal and opposite centrifugal force because the object is accelerating (since it is moving in a circle) so the forces on it are, by definition, not balanced.

However, if we use a reference frame moving with the object then the object is *not* accelerating (it is stationary) so the forces on it do need to be balanced. In this reference frame we have to introduce a centrifugal force to balance the tension in the string and so explain why the object is stationary. The centrifugal force is equal and opposite to the tension in the string.

But notice that these are two separate explanations of the motion of the object. Centrifugal force and centripetal force do not appear in the same reference frame.