# Normal reaction exerted by a rolling object

Tags: forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, rotational-kinematics, rotation

If we take a disc of mass M and radius R and assume that the disc is performing Combined rotational and translational motion on a frictionless flat surface. then if we take a point at the top of the rotating disc at any instance, we see the point has one acceleration towards the dir of motion because of linear motion (assuming the disc is moving with an acceleration 'a'). and the point has tangential acceleration towards the same dir and centripetal acceleration downwards. So will the centripetal acceleration not increase the N reaction of the disc on the group(mg - N = m (a centripetal) ). and will this be the same case if the body is pure rolling ??. This is an example image showing point A please dont pay attention to the values[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this will help or not. But if your question is about the nature of reaction forces, I talked about them in my answer to [Can the tension on a rope for example diminish due to centrifugal force and if so why do we stay in orbit; what would happen if centrifugal force won?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/791418/37364).

Comment: Its the acceleration of the center of the disk that appears in Newton II.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are saying the disc is undergoing pure rolling with  linear acceleration on a frictionless surface, which isn't possible. Static friction would be necessary.

In any event,  the normal reaction force of the supporting surface depends only on the weight of the disc, $mg$, as long as there are no external vertical forces acting on the disc other than the force of gravity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

NO, The normal reaction in this case equals to mg. The points on the disc travel in a circular path due to the virtue of angular velocity and acceleration. However, the disc itself is not traveling on a circular (or curved)path.